# 2 SBS 2011 Servers On Diffrent Subnets but DHCP clashing

Tags: windows

I'm setting up 2 SBS 2011 servers for 2 companies that share an office space they share physical network cabling, internet connection and 4 networked printers.

I've got them setup as 2 different subnets 192.168.20.0 and 192.168.30.0 the shared router is 192.168.1.254 all the clients and servers can browse through this and also print to all printers 2 on one subnet and 2 on the other.

My issue is that the DHCPs of the 2 SBS servers clash and one ends up stopping.

I understand that the router is bridging the two subnets which is why everything can browse and I can see printers on the other subnet.

How do I stop the DHCP servers from seeing the other subnets DHCP?

Comment: What are the subnet masks of everything? Can you sketch up a quick Visio or something of your environment?

Comment: Can we assume that the two subnets are actually isolated from each other by physical or logical separation, and that you aren't trying to run two subnets on one logical network?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/v8vc899vr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because DHCP works primarily at layer 2 (broadcast traffic to 255.255.255.255) and all of your computers are sharing the same layer 2 infrastructure. SBS will send a DHCP probe and if it gets a response will shut it's DHCP service down. That's why it's shutting down on one of the SBS servers. What you need to do is to provide separation at layer 2, by either using separate switches for each client or using VLAN's on the current switches.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP only crosses subnets when an IP Helper (or DHCP Relay depending on your router's terminology) is configured to pass the broadcasts from one subnet to another. Don't configure DHCP relay across these subnets.

Comment: Network diagram - http://postimg.org/image/v8vc899vr/

Comment: Oh. Yeah you should use VLANs for separation there. Just plugging everything into the same set of switches with no L2 separation like VLANs is not good.